# JavaScript (JQuery) Search By Whole Word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field where the user enters data (id test) and block in which there are data of the type:

```
<div class="someclass">3434 34, 345455, 432 423, 54563 4543, 23232, 232 323, 343 43, random numbers and letters with spaces</div>
<input type="text" id="test">`
```

How do I search for the full word? I tried to use `indexOf()`, but then when I enter the number only `345` I get a lot of results, but none corresponds to the full word.

Comment: what you should try for that

Comment: You could get the text, `split()` it in to an array, then find that exact value within the array.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery :

```js
var arr = document.querySelector('.someclass').textContent.split(',')

console.log(arr.filter(function (word) {
  return word.trim() === '345'
}))
```

```html
<div class="someclass">3434 34, 345, 455, 432 423, 54563 4543, 23232, 232 323, 343 43, random numbers and letters with spaces</div>
```